# How to make Java class to initialize another class, and execute static java code block conditionally

Tags: java, initialization, static-members, wiremock, control-flow

I am using WireMock and managed to configure it to use SSL in JUnit 4 tests and disable throwing error if the hostname doesn't match the WireMock self signed certificate with `CN=Tom Akehurst`.

The code block I added to the JUnit test class:

```
    static {
        //for localhost testing only
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(newJavaKeyword javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                if (hostname.equals("localhost")) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Note: replace `newJavaKeyword` with new as it is not posting without doing that.

The following is the error thrown if the above code is not added:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
```

Now, I need to move with testing from my local to the server, and I still need to use `WireMock` and all the configured JSON mappings. This time, the test cases will run from the main process not from JUnit, so I need to add the flag `disableVerifyLocalHost` to be passed to say class `A` which will initialize class `B`. In class `B`, I want to run the above static code block only if the the flag `disableVerifyLocalHost` is `true`.

I think I can put the code block above in a normal public method but I guess the purpose of the static code block is to ensure the code will run only once.

My understanding is the the static code block will run very early, so I need to ensure the flag `disableVerifyLocalHost` has been initialized before running the static code block above. Also, I think the flag `disableVerifyLocalHost` must be static as well.

Following is how I think this should be implemented, but not sure:

```
public class A {

   private static boolean disableVerifyLocalHost = false;
   public static setDisableVerifyLocalHost(...) {...}
   public static boolean getDisableVerifyLocalHost(.) {...}
   
   public callClassB() {
       B classB = new B()
   }
}


public class B {

    static {
        //for localhost testing only
        if (A.getDisableVerifyLocalHost()) {
            javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(newJavaKeyword javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String hostname, javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                    if (hostname.equals("localhost")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how to ensure dependency between the code to initialize the flag `disableVerifyLocalHost` and the code to disable checking the hostname `localhost`? Or if you have a better suggestion, please let me know.